# How to substract dates with excel - current date with date in format yyyyddmmhhmmss

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010, vba

Is there any option to compare dates with Date format `yyyymmddhhmmss` with the current date?
Basically one of my external source have this type of date and I have to compare this date with the `current date` and check difference in between. I have tried to split those date with `LEFT,MID,RIGHT functions`, so basically, I have two columns - first with date, second with time, but I cannot find any option to subtract current date with date in column, because results are not coming correct.

Sample of date:    `20161112203545`

after splitting: `2016-11-12 20:05:45`.

Any ideas?

Comment: Does timezone or daylight savings matter? I ask because depending on where these spreadsheets come from, where you are, and how far apart the dates are it may matter.

Answer (score 1):

Image produced below with formulas is self explanatory.

[image: finding difference in dates]

Your date :20161112203545 in `D4`

Formula to convert date in `E4` :

```
=DATE(LEFT(D4,4),MID(D4,5,2),MID(D4,7,2))+TIME(MID(D4,9,2),MID(D4,11,2),RIGHT(D4,2))
```

Today's Date in F4 : `=TODAY()`

Formula to get date difference in days in G4 : `=DATEDIF(F4,E4,"d")`

**EDIT**

The alternative to `Excel DATEDIF` would be a User defined function (UDF) that internally uses the `VBA DATEDIFF` function:

This UDF accepts three parameters:

Start_Date: The days from which the period begins.
End_Date: It is the last date of the period that you wish to calculate.
Unit: It specifies the interval by which you want the difference. Here the unit accepts following values.
Value   Description
YYYY    Year
Q   Quarter
M   Month
Y   Day of year
D   Day

```
Public Function xlDATEDIF(Start_Date As Date, End_Date As Date, Unit As String) As String  
    xlDATEDIF = DateDiff(Unit, Start_Date, End_Date)  
End Function
```

In this case usage will be, put formula in `H4` `=xlDATEDIF(F4,E4,"D")`
 HTH

Comment: Unfortunately, there is no DATEIF in Excel 2010 :/

Comment: @user4572896 DATEDIF() is there it is just a hidden formula.

Comment: @user4572896 If you are unable to use ~DATEDIF~ , I am editing my post to include a UDF. This UDF accepts three parameters:

Start_Date: The days from which the period begins.
End_Date: It is the last date of the period that you wish to calculate.
Unit: It specifies the interval by which you want the difference.

Comment: You don't need `datediff` to get the difference in days. Just simply subtract the two cells. `E4-F4`

Comment: @vacip ~E4-F4~ will give ~179.8581597~ instead of whole number ~179~ for difference in no. of days. It is also important if time component is to be mentioned. Appreciate your highlighting this point.

Answer (score 0):

Taking the date as

> 20161112203545 after splitting: 2016-11-12 20:05:45

Is going to cause you some issues as Excel assigns date values with a serial number, and it's going to throw that number off. You could use the =today() function and set it up where you have the date entered, say it is in cell A1, then =A1-today() (formatted as a number) should give you the difference in the amount of days.
[Microsoft explanation of using Dates in Excel](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Count-days-before-a-date-6e216530-f491-4e00-8f5f-e9fdc810d89c)